# Creating a .lib file - first time

Tags: c++, c, windows, static-libraries

This is my first time creating a .lib file, I have the following C++ .exe project:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib")

int myFunction(void);

void main()
{
    myFunction(); 

}
```

and another C project (the .lib project)

```
   int __cdecl myFunction(void)
   {
   }
```

I'm compiling the .lib file "mylib.lib" successfully and putting it into the compilation directory of my exe file but I'm receiving the "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" error, am I forgetting something?

Comment: Among other things, the return type for `main`. And is this C or C++?

Comment: You're right I forgot the "void". The first project is C++ while the second is C

Comment: Have you make the [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822(v=vs.80).aspx)<--(using VS) for the compiler add the lib into the proyect?

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña That is not relevant.  The `#pragma` given here includes the static lib as a linker dependency.  There is no need to specify it in the project settings.  Also, the user does not appear to be talking about DLLs.

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: Nope; `main` returns `int`, not `void`. Always.

Comment: Wich IDE or compiler are you using?

Comment: Did you tried what i post before? it should be working, since its the "manual" way of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you provide a header for your lib, and include that in both the lib and the user.

Firstly, you should use the `extern` keyword on the function declaration.  And because you have specified the calling convention `__cdecl` you should be consistent:

**mylib.h**

```
extern int __cdecl myFunction(void);
```

**mylib.cpp**

```
#include "mylib.h"

int __cdecl myFunction(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

**libuser.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib")

int main(void)
{
    printf( "The answer to the question is %d\n", myFunction() ); 
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit** -- name mangling...

I just saw your comment about the projects being C and C++.  In this case you have to help the compiler with symbol mangling that occurs.  In your header, you do this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int __cdecl myFunction(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Damn I keep getting "unresolved external symbol myFunction referenced in function main"

Comment: Please check and double-check your capitalisation, return type and parameter list.  It must match everywhere.  Make sure you've handled the C++ name mangling I mentioned in my edit.  Make sure you have used the `extern` keyword.  And make sure you've copied the correct lib, and that your project is looking in the right place.  It may be picking up an old version somewhere else.

Comment: I think it's not a name mangling problem anymore because here's dumpbin /symbols output: "13B 00000000 SECT5  notype ()    External     | _myFunction" so the function is exported... still my cpp program can't see it. I've doublechecked every string

Comment: uhm is that "_" on _myFunction added by dumpbin or what? Could be the problem?

Comment: That's what the `extern "C"` handles when compiling from C++.  Maybe you need to remove the `extern` from the declaration of `myFunction` in that case.  Not sure, now that I think of it.

Comment: This answer seems good to me but I have something to add: did you pay attention that all your objects are compiled for the same architecture? I mean: if you have a 32bit object, it should be linked with other 32bit objects. You can't link 32 and 64 bit code interchangeably